# STM43F4 Discovery: How to read flash device by SPI?

Tags: stm32f4discovery

I need to read Device ID of flash device W25Q32FV.
In W25Q32FV document write: "The Read Manufacturer/Device ID instruction is an alternative to the Release from Power-down / Device
ID instruction that provides both the JEDEC assigned manufacturer ID and the specific device ID.
The Read Manufacturer/Device ID instruction is very similar to the Release from Power-down / Device ID
instruction. The instruction is initiated by driving the /CS pin low and shifting the instruction code “90h”
followed by a 24-bit address (A23-A0) of 000000h. After which, the Manufacturer ID for Winbond (EFh)
and the Device ID are shifted out on the falling edge of CLK with most significant bit (MSB) first as shown
in Figure 39. The Device ID values for the W25Q32FV are listed in Manufacturer and Device Identification
table. The instruction is completed by driving /CS high."

[image: Figure 39]

And my code for STM32F4 Dicovery(STM32F407VGTx):

```
#define spi_enable HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define spi_disable HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET)

spi_enable;
uint8_t read_id = 0x90;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &read_id, 1, 1000);

address[0] = 0x00;address[1] = 0x00;address[2] = 0x00;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, address, 3, 1000);

HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &manualId, 1, 1000);
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &deviceId, 1, 1000);    

spi_disable;
```

The init function:

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
    hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
    hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
    hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
    hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
    hspi1.Init.CLKPhase=SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
    hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
    hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler=SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
    hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
    hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
    hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
    if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
}
```

It does not work :(

Comment: Have you checked the polarity and phase when you set up the SPI? To be exhaustive, could you share the SPI init code and the contents of your spi_enable/disable functions.

Comment: Yes: #define spi_enable   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET)
#define spi_disable   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET)

Comment: SPI init:
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase=SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler=SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
}

Answer (score 0):

The sequences should be MSB first. So replace

```
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
```

by

```
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
```

in the `void MX_SPI1_Init(void)`.
The best way to do it is to update STMCube of course.

Comment: Thank, i will try it